# Game Development for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, game-engine, unreal-development-kit

Can we develop games for Android and iOS on Unreal Development Kit? I am planning to make games for both platforms, so my questions are:

- Will I have to make games separately for different platforms?
- Is developing games for mobile platforms different than developing for PC?

I have made a little game for PC. Is game development process the same for mobile platforms

I know this a noob question but I want to clear myself.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UDK for both iOS and Android platform, you can refer to this answer of mine for more details. The same question was asked on game development.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23222/4781

For your second question, yes the the development is different but only the controls will change as for mobile devices you dont have the keyboard or mouse as input, but on the other end you can explore gyroscope, accelerometer and touches as the inputs.

Rest everything will remain the same.

As a note, the textures will be changed to png files in UDK instead of packages. There is a small setting in model object in UDK that you can set the mobile texture, you will find that info on there website and at many places teaching you about UDK.

Comment: Have you made any game for mobile platforms on UDK

Comment: Yes and i have run one of them successfully on the device too. But take my advice, if you are new to UDK or dont have a lot of knowledge on it then just go with the unity it is much more faster and good for beginners.

Comment: Your unity suggestion seems good for me. Have been thinking about it too :)

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to make games separately for different platforms. You can use [Unity - Game Engine](http://unity3d.com/). This engine allows you to develop cross-platform games for those platforms: Windows, Xbox 360, Windows RT, Windows Phone, Mac, iOS, Android, Nintendo Wii, PlayStation 3, Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: An excellent engine too.

Comment: I know UDK a little bit so I would like to develop on it. I don't want to start from scratch